# Formatting cookies.json into requests(cookies) Python

Tags: python, html, authentication, cookies, request

How can I use my cookie.json file in python request and log in website with this cookie cookies. This is my json file example:

```
[
{
    "domain": "example.com",
    "expirationDate": 161551211,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "usernameexample",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": null,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": null,
    "value": "878203952"
},
{
    "domain": "example.com",
    "expirationDate": 164813154441,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "usernameexample",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "..x",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": null,
    "value": "is
},...]
```

Comment: Because it doesn't work? Edit your text and report the problem

Comment: Set-Cookie: <em>value</em>[; expires=<em>date</em>][; domain=<em>domain</em>][; path=<em>path</em>][; secure] is the typical format of a cookie. From: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/